# How can I divide a large number by 1 without converting to floating point in Javascript

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I have a code that needs to check if the number of seconds given can make up a year, but when argument of 1 second is passed, the function goes nuts!

```js
const isUpToYear = seconds => parseInt(seconds / 31536000) >= 1;

console.log(isUpToYear(311536000));  // true
console.log(isUpToYear(3600));  // false
console.log(isUpToYear(1));    // true!!
```

Clearly, I need the function to return false if a second is passed in.
How do I fix this?

Comment: why are you using parseInt on a number??? What happens is this `parseInt((1/31536000).toString())` That is your problem! You should be using modulus or ceil or floor. You can figure it out.

Comment: Oops, I wanted to convert said number to an integer so I could display the number of years that could be gotten from the given seconds if any. Guess Math.floor() is the toool

Comment: Note: `31536000` differs from `311536000`.

Comment: Yes @chux, I merely wanted to include it as a test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseInt` is intended to be used on a *string*. The first argument passed to `parseInt` gets converted to a string, [if it isn't one already](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> The value to parse. If this argument is not a string, then it is converted to one using the ToString abstract operation. Leading whitespace in this argument is ignored.

And `1 / 31536000` is small: `3.1709791983764586e-8`. Calling `parseInt` on this results in it getting converted to a string (`'3.1709791983764586e-8'`), which, converted back into a number again, results in `3`, understandably (because `3` is the only leading digit character in the string).

Use `Math.floor` instead.

```js
const isUpToYear = seconds => Math.floor(seconds / 31536000) >= 1;

console.log(isUpToYear(311536000));  // true
console.log(isUpToYear(3600));  // false
console.log(isUpToYear(1));    // true!!
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to convert said number to an integer so I could display the number of years that could be gotten from the given seconds if any. Guess Math.floor() is the tool

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.floor()` instead of `parseInt()` here.

The `parseInt()` function is useful when you have a string that looks like an integer, and you want it as an integer value.  The problem is that the float value is being cast to a string like `"3.1709...e-8"`, and `parseInt()` understands the `3` part!